# Hard query with aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I'm using Oracle SQL, and i need help with a hard query.

I have two tables
(`table_A`):

```
GroupID (int)
ClientID (int)
Age (int)
```

(`table_B`):

```
GroupID (int)
Budget (int)
```

My query should do for each group of clients:

- Calculate the average ages of the group
- Calculate the average budget
  of each clients with age like the average age (The age can be bigger or smaller in
  1). For example: Average_Age - 1 < Average_Age < Average_Age + 1.
- `Output value`: (Budget) / (Average Budget)

For example: 
`table_A`:

```
GroupID | ClientID  | Age
    A   |   11      | 26
    A   |   22      | 27
    A   |   33      | 21
    B   |   44      | 22
    B   |   55      | 29
    B   |   66      | 25
    C   |   77      | 23
    C   |   88      | 22
    C   |   99      | 20
    D   |   111     | 24
    D   |   222     | 26
    D   |   333     | 25
```

`table_B`:

```
GroupID | Budget
   A    |  100
   B    |  200
   C    |  300
   D    |  400
```

None of the values in the tables are fixed.
Example of calculation of the Output Value of Group A:

- Average ages in group A: (27+27+21) / 3 = 24.6
- The ClientIDs with ages of 23-25 are: 66, 77, 111, 333.  Their Average budget is:
  (200+300+400*2)/4 = 325
- The output value should be: 100 / 325  = 0.307

The output table should be

```
 GroupID    |  Output Value
    A       |     0.307
    B       |     ....
    C       |     ....
    D       |     ....
```

Any recommendations how to do that? I've tried so many ways. I'm feel lost.

Comment: `None of the values in the tables are not fixed.`  -  So, are all the values fixed? (For clarity's sake)

Comment: Sorry. All of them are not fixed (i changed it above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare test data (fixed typo in name and type):

```
drop table table_a;

create table table_a(
GroupID  varchar2(10),
ClientID int,
Age      int
);

drop table table_b;

create table table_b(
GroupID varchar2(10),
Budget  int
);


insert into table_a values('A',   11  , 26);
insert into table_a values('A',   22  , 27);
insert into table_a values('A',   33  , 21);
insert into table_a values('B',   44  , 22);
insert into table_a values('B',   55  , 29);
insert into table_a values('B',   66  , 25);
insert into table_a values('C',   77  , 23);
insert into table_a values('C',   88  , 22);
insert into table_a values('C',   99  , 20);
insert into table_a values('D',   111 , 24);
insert into table_a values('D',   222 , 26);
insert into table_a values('D',   333 , 25);

insert into table_b values('A',   100);
insert into table_b values('B',   200);
insert into table_b values('C',   300);
insert into table_b values('D',   400);

commit;
```

The query itself:

```
select a1.GroupId, a2.groupid, a2.clientid, b1.budget/avg(b2.budget) over(partition by a1.groupid) as avg_budget
 from (select GroupId, trunc(avg(age)) as avg_age
        from table_a
       group by GroupId
     ) a1
 inner join table_a a2
    on a2.age between a1.avg_age - 1 and a1.avg_age + 1
 inner join table_b b1
    on b1.groupid = a1.groupid    
 inner join table_b b2
    on b2.groupid = a2.groupid    
order by a1.GroupId, a2.clientid
;
```

Result:

```
GROUPID GROUPID_1   CLIENTID    AVG_BUDGET
A   B   66  0.307692307692308
A   C   77  0.307692307692308
A   D   111 0.307692307692308
A   D   333 0.307692307692308
B   A   11  0.666666666666667
B   B   66  0.666666666666667
B   D   111 0.666666666666667
B   D   222 0.666666666666667
B   D   333 0.666666666666667
C   A   33  1.33333333333333
C   B   44  1.33333333333333
C   C   88  1.33333333333333
C   C   99  1.33333333333333
D   A   11  1.33333333333333
D   B   66  1.33333333333333
D   D   111 1.33333333333333
D   D   222 1.33333333333333
D   D   333 1.33333333333333
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you very much. This is not a trivial query at all. I'm not sure i completely understood the query.  I have a few questions: 1. Why did you use trunc() function? 2. Why did you use the table "table_b" twice in the inner join? 3. I need to extend the query with two more column in the final table: In addition to "Average ages in group A" in the first step, i need "Maximum Age In group A" and "Minumum Age in group A". All i need is to add a two new columns in the inner select with "trunc(max(age))" and "trunc(min(age))" and two more in the outer?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not able to use your query. It runs too much time. Each one of the tables has about 20,000 records. The final proposal is to run this query on much bigger tables (10 times bigger). Is there any way to make the query run faster?

Comment: 1. You said: Average_Age - 1 < Average_Age < Average_Age + 1. For your example avg age is 24.6. Nest satetment - The ClientIDs with ages of 23-25 are... So why 23-25? only if 24.6 => 24. 2. To get what you need. Please scrutinize the query - to has different grouping level so it requires self joins/ I think you can replace it with analytic function if you wish. It is up to you. 3. That's already you know better what you need. I gave you base idea you can apply it on real-life task.

Comment: In terms of performance try to use analytic function instead self joins and group by. Consider to add indexes.

Comment: Indexes has been added. Still working too much slowly. In addition, table_a has 40k records and table_b has 20k. The distinct number of records in table_a is equal to table_b (both has the same groups). However, when selecting the whole query with "select count(*)" instead of selecting the selected columns from the query, it gives me more than 68m records, and i guess that's the reason for the slow performance.

Comment: The reason for the huge number of records is because each client is matching thousands of times for each group. It's very reasonable since the matching is by age and most of clients in the table are in the same range of ages (20-50).

Answer (score 0):

```
select Q1.GroupID, Q2.Budget/Q1.Budget_avg as Output_value from
(
select GroupID,ClientID,avg(budget) as Budget_avg from table_A A,table_B B
where A.GroupID =B.GroupID
group by GroupID,ClientID
) Q1,(select GroupID,Budget from table_B) Q2
where Q1.GroupID = Q2.GroupID
```

Can you try this and let me know if this works for you?